# Quarkus: Custom JSON logging format

Tags: jboss, vert.x, quarkus, microprofile

I'm using the quarkus-logging-json artifact. Is there a way to add custom fields in the json logs?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't such a capability. You are welcome to open an issue on Github with the details of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @geoand Everyone can follow the issue here https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/7451